# Code works in console but not in source, because of the encoding

Tags: r, windows, encoding, rstudio

My source files with R scripts were working just fine. Recently I copied them to another computer (Windows too), but now these scripts just aren't working, because of the encoding problems. First of all, scripts became corrupted and after I fixed them, I still can't run it. Whatever I do (whatever encoding I use), mistakes appear.

At the same time, if I copy the code to the console, it works just fine. I've broken my head on it and would appreciate any help. The problem is with Cyrillic symbols.

Here is a small example:

```
data <- data.frame('имя' = c("1", "2"), values = c(1, 2))
text <- c("раз", "два", "три")
column <- data$имя
```

As I said, this code works in console, but not in source. I've tried to follow the advices given in other questions about problems with Cyrillic encoding, but without any positive result.

Comment: Added the windows tag because encoding issues are generally different between win* and *nix OSes. I also think there is not enough material here. I'm on a Mac but even if I were on a -doze machine, I don't see a clear description about the input files, code , and an explicit way to tell if you get success. The second line makes reference to an object that is not in the workspace.

Comment: And I cannot get any errors with loading this text in Rstudio after saving with a text editor.

Comment: Have you tried to specify the encoding in `source`? E.g. `source("myscript.R", encoding = "windows-1251")` - or maybe `"UTF-8"`, or `"KOI8-R"`... If it's not one of those 3, `readr::guess_encoding` could help you.

Comment: @42- Done. Well, the problem is - this works perfectly on some PCs, but not on a new one. I hope, that its working in console is a key.

Comment: @Scarabee but before you start calling source() method, you need to save it. And when you save, you already use encoding. Yes, I tried using different encoding. But I don't know why everything works in console and at the same time, there is no encoding to run the source file I can find. What am I not doing or doing wrong?

Comment: I'm wondering if different environment variables may be in play in the two situations (console vs. Rscript)? Maybe you could try running a simple script without the offending characters and seeing if printing out the results of `Sys.getenv()` might be informative?